# Using AJAX to call a PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to call a PHP script. I am using conditions to echo the proper error message in my PHP. When I do this, my AJAX and JQUERY do not work properly.

My JQUERY/AJAX:

```
        if (email != 0) {
            // Run AJAX email validation and check to see if the email is already taken
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "checkemail.php",  
                data: dataString,
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    var error= false;

                    if (data == 'invalid') {
                        var invalid= 1;
                    }
                    else if (data == 'taken') {
                        var taken= 1;
                    }
                    if (invalid == 1) {
                        alert('invalid email');
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                    if (taken == 1) {
                        alert('email taken');
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

My PHP:

```
<?php

$email = true

if ($email == true) {

    echo "taken";

}


?>
```

But, when I just put:

```
echo "taken";
```

The AJAX and JQUERY works exactly how it should and the respective error message pops up. "taken" is being echo'd either way, so I don't get what is going on. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You should test your PHP code before making ajax request to them.

Comment: This is [**you**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164490/form-validation-with-jquery-and-ajax#comment31859004_21164490) I suppose

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8, the use of `async:false` in `jQuery.ajax()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing your semicolon.

```
$email = true
```

needs to be

```
$email = true;
```

In your response, you will probably be getting a PHP error - unless your error messages are suppressed.